# I have a Delphi assignment. If I input text into my edit box and it’s less than 6 letters than it mustn’t be allowed, if is then works

Tags: delphi, variable-assignment

I'm pretty sure my problem is due to an If statement.

I have to make a procedure where if I insert a certain amount of
characters into the edit box and that amount is less than 5 then it will tell me “showmessage’please ensure that the password is more than 5 characters’; but if it’s more than five letters than it would print it on the Memo form. But I want to make it all in 1 button.
Any ideas?

```
var, var
sName : string ;

sName := edit1.text ;
if edit1.text > 6 then
begin
  showmessage’please ensure that etc.’
end;
```

this doesn’t seem to be working and I think it’s because the string and integer doesn’t work together.

Comment: In the code you also seem to have the logic opposite to the requirement. Do you spot it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct - you are trying to compare a string with a number, which is a no-go in Delphi.

You need to check the *length* of the inputted text, so the IF statement should be:

```
if length(edit1.text) > 6 then
```

Also, note that *you* say "more than 5" but your *code* says "larger than 6".

Answer (score 0):

`TEdit` has a `GetTextLen()` method which returns the number of characters entered:

```pascal
if Edit1.GetTextLen < 5 then
begin
  ShowMessage('please ensure that etc.');
end else
begin
  // use Edit1.Text as needed...
end;
```